# Theorem 3.19 (The Third Isomorphism Theorem) from Dummit's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I'm reading the proof of this Theorem 3.19 (The Third Isomorphism Theorem) from Dummit's Abstract Algebra page 98:

[image]

I could understand the proof. What I cannot understand is how could we use an undefined $K/H$ in the theorem?

If you need to read the proof, it goes as following:

[image]

Comment: In what sense is $K/H$ not defined for you?

Comment: Because $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $K$.

Comment: @AriRoyceHidayat It is not stated that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $K$, but since it is a normal subgroup of $G$, it follows that it is a normal subgroup of $K$. Infact, for all $g \in K$ you have $gHg^{-1}=H$, because $g \in G$ and $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: You beat me to it, @Crostul! Please consider writing up your comment as an answer.

Comment: Please do not rely on images: they are not searchable, they may not display properly in all interfaces, and some screen readers cannot handle them. Use Mathjax instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H\unlhd G$, we have $gHg^{-1}=H$ for all $g\in G$. In particular, $kHk^{-1}=H$ for all $k\in K\unlhd G$. Hence $H\unlhd K$.